# How to make jQuery Mobile apply enhancement after Knockout applyBindings()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I use an ajax call to fetch data from server and bind them using `ko.applyBindings()`. But JQM applied enhancement before this binding, which breaks things. How can I make JQM not to apply enhancement automatically but **explicitly** (by calling something like `enhanceWithin`) after `ko.applyBindings()`.

[Without Ajax Call (Things work well)](https://jsfiddle.net/Richard_Liu/x3mLdnt6/)

[With Ajax Call (Things break)](https://jsfiddle.net/Richard_Liu/3pxg0f6q/)

Comment: small fix does it `@Fix-it Felix Jr.` . check here https://jsfiddle.net/3pxg0f6q/5/ . let us know

Comment: @supercool check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Richard_Liu/fwo7zya2/). 1. Why does it work fine if there are some data initially? (Seems the initial data creates a valid template page that the later pushed data can mimic). 2. It's more often that there is no initial data. How to tackle this situation? thx.

Comment: you can use `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(false);` to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `autoInitializePage` to false.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
});
```

and then call `$.mobile.initializePage();` explicitly.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Richard_Liu/fwo7zya2/)

Comment: glad you too figured it out . well i am looking into mobile.css placing tough `mobile.js` at end does the trick .